# Possible security hole using SetDllDirectory?

Tags: security, dll

I've got a DLL which makes a call to [SetDllDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203(VS.85).aspx) in its DllMain() function. The argument to SetDllDirectory() is the directory in which the DLL resides, as returned by the [GetModuleFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197(VS.85).aspx) function. The effect of this is that if the DLL is placed as `c:/foo/bar.dll`, then loading `bar.dll` will add `c:/foo` to the DLL search path of the calling process.

My question is: does this open up any form of security hole? Would it be safer to perform the SetDllDirectory() call in a function which had to be explicitly called by the process loading the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't. Well actually not a new one. Since the application path is the first place windows looks for dlls someone could place a malicious dll in this folder. So there is a security hole without your SetDllDirectory() call.